# While loop and Jquery append Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, while-loop

First question here! Hope you can help me. I'm trying to make 16 squares side by side using a Javascript while loop but I don't understand why it doesn't work. I'm new to Javascript and jQuery so please excuse me if the answer is too simple. Thank you in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var divs = $("<div class='square'></div>");
  var i = 0;
  while (i < 17) {
    $("#wrapper").append(divs);
    i++;
  }

});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 70px auto;
}
.square {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">

    <div class="square"></div>

  </div>
</body>
```

**strong text**

Comment: There is no for loop we can see. Did you mean while loop?

Comment: Where is `for` loop mentioned in the title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the loop, in each iteration you need to create a new object, else it will be just like replacing the same element so many times

So you can just [clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone) the element in the loop

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var divs = $("<div class='square'></div>");
  var i = 0;
  while (i < 17) {
    $("#wrapper").append(divs.clone());
    i++;
  }

});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 70px auto;
}
.square {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">

  <div class="square"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

updating this part of your code :

```
var divs =  "<div class='square'></div>";
```

so your code will be  :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var divs =  "<div class='square'></div>";
  var i = 0;
  while (i < 17) {
    $("#wrapper").append(divs);
    i++;
  }

});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 70px auto;
}
.square {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">

    <div class="square"></div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to append div so just write html code in divs var

change your code to

```
var divs = "<div class='square'></div>"
```

Instead of

```
var divs = $("<div class='square'></div>");
```